# No database provider has been configured for this DbContext - ASP.Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am getting the below error :

> InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Startup.cs :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    services.AddSession(options=>{options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);});services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            options.Cookie.Name = "SampleCore";
            options.LoginPath = "/log-in";
            //options.AccessDeniedPath = "/access-denied";
            options.LogoutPath = "/log-off";
            options.ReturnUrlParameter = "postBack";
        });
    services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection");
    services.AddDbContext<EmployeeContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);   
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseCustomErrorPages();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

UseCustomErrorPages Extension :

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        await _next(context); // Getting error at this line
        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !context.Response.HasStarted)
        {
            string originalPath = context.Request.Path.Value;
            context.Items["originalPath"] = originalPath;
            context.Request.Path = "/page-not-found";
            await _next(context);
        }
        else if (context.Response.StatusCode == 500)
        {
            string originalPath = context.Request.Path.Value;
            context.Items["originalPath"] = originalPath;
            context.Request.Path = "/error";
            await _next(context);
        }
        else if(context.Response.StatusCode == 401)
        {
            string originalPath = context.Request.Path.Value;
            context.Items["originalPath"] = originalPath;
            context.Request.Path = "/access-denied";
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
```

DbContext :

```
public partial class EmployeeContext : DbContext
{
    public EmployeeContext(DbContextOptions<EmployeeContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            var connectionString = "connectionString";
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }

    public virtual DbSet<TblEmployee> TblEmployee { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Code
    }
}
```

csproj file :

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.4">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.6" />
```

Controller :

```
private EmployeeContext _context;
public HomeController(EmployeeContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
public List<TblEmployee> GetEmployees
{
   List<TblEmployee> getEmployees = _context.TblEmployee.ToList();
   return getEmployees ;
}
```

appsettings.json :

```
{
  "Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Warning"
  }
 },
"ConnectionStrings": {
"MyConnection": "connection string"
},
"AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I don't understand where I did wrong. Kindly help

Comment: SUGGESTION: Make sure you have a valid connection string in your `appsettings.json`.  The usual name is "DefaultConnection"; your .json needs a connection string with the name ""MyConnection".

Comment: Thanks for your reply @paulsm4. I am able to read the connection string from appsettings.json file.

Comment: TWO SUGGESTIONS: 1) Change your debug level to "Trace", 2) Try to recreate the problem in a [small, self contained example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Fail to reproduce your issue with your code, is there any demo project to reproduce your issue? Have you run command to create and update the database?

Comment: Hi @TaoZhou, Thanks for your reply. I have an already existing db. So I ran a scaffold command to get the entities in my project.

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue with a new simple existing db? If you can, share us detail steps.

Comment: Hi @TaoZhou, I tried to reproduce the issue in a small contained example. I am able to get the records from the db. But don't understand whats wrong with the above code. I think the problem lies in UseCustomErrorPages Extension method. Is that correct or do I need to do any changes to that extension?